# Bluetooth not showing after Pair

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, windows-8

I have a win8.1 tablet and can Pair the 14.04 with it, but the tablet does not show up in the 14.04 Bluetooth drop-down from the top bar. I need to be able to transfer files between the two.

The Bluetooth icon is showing the Padlock so it seems to be Paired and the win8.1 thinks it sent a file OK. How do I then transfer files from 14.04 if there is no menu item to use the "Send Files" option?

I have cleared both devices Bluetooth, rebooted and Paired both. Still can't get a menu item in 14.04.

Both seem to auto-connect OK on restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that an OBEX DEB package is installed, and also start the app "personal file sharing" and verify the current setup.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, should have mentioned that I can transfer via BT with the phone OK and the personal-file-sharing settings are fine.  Synaptic shows six OBEX items installed, including "gnome-bluetooth" I do not know how else to check for the OBEX DEB, I am new to Ubutnu/Linux.

Comment: At settings/Bluetooth click the Windows paired device and check for the "send files" button.

Comment: Also is file transfer working both ways with the phone? If only one way then OBEX package is installed, but missing the server package or missing the client package. Or the OBEX protocol used to share files with Windows.

Comment: Thanks again, There is no "Send button" visible. It is shows "Paired" and the "Connection ON" button is grayed out - but the padlock is shown in the top bar, suggesting to me that it is connected as that's what happens when I connect the phone (turned fully-off at the moment while I sort this out) . The win tablet shows it as "Connected"

Comment: Yes, phone worked both ways OK.

Comment: OBEX: obex-data-server, obex-client, libopenobex1, gnome-bluetooth, gnome-user-share gvfs-backends all appear int Synaptic as Installed

Comment: Try install Obex-ftp or Obex-smb and other Obex-??? and reboot maybe the button appears. Usually have two buttons at right-lower "send files" and "browse phone" (or similar, that mounts the phone or tablet as a disk in Nautilus).

Comment: The Nautilus options show up when the phone is connected, but not the win-tablet (I had set Shared folders) anywhere. But, moot point, I have just installed NitroShare on both devices and it is working fine. Not quite as convenient as BT, but will go with it as it is working and beats USB-sneaker-net. Thanks again for taking the time to try and help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Package necessary are (I confirmed): obexftp and obexfs, and maybe obextools